# GWT - How to generate the *.nocache.js

Tags: java, gwt

If I create a GWT project in eclipse without checking the checkbox "generate sample code", I will get a pretty empty project (as expected). There is a wizard for all the needed files:

- The module.gwt.xml
- The entry point
- The .html file

But: How can I generate the needed module.nocache.js file?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need not to generate it manually and not encouraged by google too.

Once you [compile your gwt project](http://www.gwtproject.org/doc/latest/tutorial/compile.html),It generates.